# Selecting specific text from an xml file using R

Tags: xml, r, parsing

I need to select specific text from within an xml document using R. The syntax before and after the area I need to pull is constant so it will work with many xml files when i run it through my script.

For example using a mock xml document..

```
<head>
  <image name="test1">
    <nodes>
      <alt>Synthesis1</alt>
    </node>
    <body> There is a lot of text in this section, THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO SELECT, Here is some more text in the section
    </body>
    <body> Here is the next section, THIS IS AGAIN WHAT I NEED TO SELECT, Here is more text afterwards
    </body>
  </image>
</head>
```

I've been using the XML package in R with no luck. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse('<head>
  <image name="test1">
    <nodes>
      <alt>Synthesis1</alt>
    </node>
    <body> There is a lot of text in this section, THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO SELECT, Here is some more text in the section
    </body>
    <body> Here is the next section, THIS IS AGAIN WHAT I NEED TO SELECT, Here is more text afterwards
    </body>
  </image>
</head>')
doc["//body"]
```

or

```
sapply(doc["//body"], xmlValue, trim = TRUE)
# [1] "There is a lot of text in this section, THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO SELECT, Here is some more text in the section"
# [2] "Here is the next section, THIS IS AGAIN WHAT I NEED TO SELECT, Here is more text afterwards"
```